# Why I cant Ping An Address across my a routed link

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, ping, eigrp

I have two layer 3 switches (Main And back up) and a palo alto firewall

main switch connects to the firewall with a routed link port(gi1/1 ip add 10.1.70.2)- firewall (10.1.70.1). All connectivity is good at this point (ping successful)

Back up switch is connected to the main switch with a routed link (gi 1/1 ip 10.1.70.5) main switch(gi /24 ip add 10.1.70.6)

PROBLEM:
Both switches are running EIGRP(Network 10.1.70.0) and I can ping successfully from the back up switch to the main switch IP address 10.1.70.2. the problen is I cannot ping the firewall from the backup switch(10.1.70.1).

However the vlans created on the backup switch if i connect a pc to a port assigned with that vlan it pings the firewall and routes to the internet with no problems! I just cant ping the firewall from the CLI of my back up switch. Im going bananas..lol

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A router (layer-3 switch, included) doesn't route from one network to the same network. If you had two different networks, one on each side, of the first switch, the layer-3 switch could route from one network to the other, and the ping should succeed.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about L3 interfaces and EIGRP, we must assume this:

```
Network1: Switch1 - Firewall

Network2: Switch2 - Switch1
```

First. You need to set-up on your firewall EIGRP(on the way to LEARN all the routes, i thinking It don´t knows how to reach youre second switch), but, STOP, you HAVE a Palo Alto firewall, i know that EIGRP is a Cisco Propietary Routing Protocol, then, you need to set-up a DEFAULT route to Switch1(10.1.70.2).

This can be a possible solution to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your setup:

Backup-swi_Gi1/1 -- _Gi1/24_Main-swi_Gi1/1 -- Firewall

If you have both interfaces in routing mode on main swi, you should make sure the subnets do not overlap. This is not apparent from your question. Could you please share a bit more of the config, like the interface and routing table output on all devices?